# How to manipulate variable value using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I am testing a method using `JUnit` and I am facing a confusing situation. The main purpose of this test is to enhance the branch coverage using `Cobertura`. I am passing an argument of type `String` which is added into the `DataSet`. If the key is not found on the `Map` the method simply returns `null` which I am covering as a Negative scenario.

The confusing line is

`if( o != null && o.getClass() == String.class )`

So if the key is there it would get populated in `o` but how would I make `o == null` to cover branch coverage. If `key = null` then it would never go inside the `if block`.

Method under test

```
public String getValueAsString( String key ) {
    if( this.values.containsKey( key ) ) {
        Object o = this.values.get( key );

        if( o != null && o.getClass() == String.class ) {
            String s = (String)o;
            if( s != null && !"".equals( s ) && !StringConstants.NULL_STRING.equals(s) ) {
                return s.trim();
            }
        } else if( o != null && ( o.getClass() == Calendar.class || o.getClass() == GregorianCalendar.class ) ) {
            Calendar c = (Calendar)o;
            return DateUtil.getDateAsString( c.getTimeInMillis() );
        } else if( o != null && ( o.getClass() == int.class || o.getClass() == Integer.class || 
                o.getClass() == short.class || o.getClass() == Short.class || o.getClass() == Float.class ) ) {
            return String.valueOf( o );
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

JUnit test

```
@Test
public void testGetValueAsStringNegativeScenario() throws Exception {
    String key1 = "Java Key";
    String key2 = ".NET Key";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.setType("JUnit Key");
    dataSet.addValueToDataSet(key2, "Java value");

    String answer = dataSet.getValueAsString(key1);

    assertNull(answer);
    assertSame("Java value", dataSet.getValueAsString(key2));
    assertEquals("JUnit Key", dataSet.getType());
}
```

Is it possible to test it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd not have a value under that key. Why can't you just pass in a key that doesn't exist in the values? Unrelated, but the multiple `null` checks seems like a strong code smell to me. Also unrelated, but why bother using `else if` with the additional boilerplate when you could just return?

Comment: Couldn't you replace:
`if (o != null && o.getClass() == String.class)`
by:
`if (o instanceof String)`
to eliminate confusion?

Comment: I cannot change the code but your first answer gave me an hint. If I pass key with a `null` value it would make `0` as null since the key is there but the value is `null` so it enters the `if block` and checks if `o == null`